# Testing the value of WP_USE_THEMES constant in Wordpress template loader

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in the process of learning PHP and WordPress Development.

I am trying to understand the WordPress code and I started with the `index.php`.

I understood that `index.php` defined a constant `WP_USE_THEMES` as `TRUE`

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', TRUE);
```

This is then picked up by `wp-includes/template-loader.php`.

I figured out that template-loader tried to see if `WP_USE_THEMES` is defined but I did not understand what exactly the following statement means. Could you please explain to me what exactly the following code block means.

```
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is checking to see if 1) The constant is set and 2) if it is true or not.

If either of those conditions are not met, then either the code in the line right after it, or the code in between any brackets right after it will not run.

Constant is true

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', TRUE);
    if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
       //code runs
```

Constant is not true

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
   //code does not run
```

Constant is not set

```
 if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
       //code does not run
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far are correct, but incomplete as an explanation of this code.
More specifically, if you just tested for WP_USE_THEMES and it was not defined then you would get an error and the code would stop there. So the 2 conditions have to be present and in that order, if it is NOT defined() then the second test for if it is true is not processed and so there is no error.
You will often see this type of conditinal testing:

```
if(isset($_POST['var']) && $_POST['var'] === true){
```

is another typical example. Was the var posted and if so does it equal true.

One further thing to watch out for is the type of shorthand that your example shows: the implicit test for true. Perfectly valid and faster to write, but not as explicit as it could be. It is also possible to introduce a bug because many things will evaluate to true/false while not being an explicit boolean and there will be many situations where this will matter. That is why my example uses the type equality test (===).

So as you learn to use the language you must also learn to be as explicit as possible and to make your code as easy to comprehend as possible. Otherwise when you come to modify it next year you will be scratching your head trying to remember what your code is doing and why.

Answer (score 1):

To give a bit more background - this is a bit of defensive programming.

Essentially the "main" thing this condition does, is check to see if WP_USE_THEMES is true.

However, it adds an additional check first to see if WP_USE_THEMES is even defined, before attempting to check its value. In many languages, a logical AND condition is evaluated one condition at a time, and if the first condition is FALSE, then the AND evaluation is halted and an overall value of FALSE is returned. (This is because the second part of the AND conditional is irrelevant - FALSE && X will always return FALSE, regardless of what X is.) So this just prevents any possible errors or flags if WP_USE_THEMES is undefined, before the actual TRUE/FALSE check is done.

Similarly, OR evaluations will halt early if the first part evaluates to TRUE, as TRUE || X will always return TRUE, regardless of what X is.

Answer (score 0):

If `WP_THEMES` is [defined()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php), which it is `AND` ([Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)) if it is `true` which it is.